# Sending multiple messages to JMS queue in Mule

Tags: queue, jms, rabbitmq, mule, mule-studio

I am new to Mule. I am using RabbitMQ. In my Mule studio, I have configured AMQP in Mule studio.

I am able to run a flow where I put one message read from HTTP endpoint payload and put into a queue.

Now, I need to send multiple messages, say 1000, to that queue at a time. One option is that I hit the url in the browser that many times but that is very time consuming. I want to send 1000 messages at one go. How can i do that in mule? or How should I proceed with it?

Comment: What is your target? Sending 1000 messages to HTTP endpoint or to the Queue. Based  on that we can decide if it should be done outside mule or inside Mule flow.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your trying to load test your Mule app. I would use something like Apache JMeter. JMeter will allow you to enter the url of your endpoint and set how many times to call it and many other more advanced features.

A good blog post on using JMeter and Mule is available here: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/measuring-the-performance-of-your-mule-esb-application/